# Display images with jQuery UI Dialog widget like in FancyBox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I just started using jQuery with themes and CSS framework. I am doing some dialogs for my AJAX calls and all works well but I've a problem with showing images.

I used in the past FancyBox to simply preview images in the same pages, applying a class to the anchor and then doing something like: `$("a.example.").fancybox();`.

There is someway to do it this with jQuery UI Dialog?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Html

```
<a class="preview" href="#" />
<div class="myImage">
   <img src="http://myimage.png" alt="myimage" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.myImage
{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("a.preview").click(function() {
    $('div.myImage').dialog();
});
```